# python multithread not stop in if statements

Tags: python

if i make requests with multi thread if statements not pass correct

```
# UserAgent
def getRandomUserAgent():
    user_agents = [
            #Windows 10
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.63 Safari/537.36,gzip(gfe)',
            #MAC
            'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 EdgiOS/100.1185.50 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1.15',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36',
        ]

    return user_agents[randint(0, len(user_agents) - 1)]

#Query Default:
def getQUERY():
    with open('query.default','r') as f:
        list = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            list.append(line)
        return list


#URL List:
def getURL():
    with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
        list = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            list.append(line)
        return list

# Do Work
def URLopen(xquery):
    my_headers  = { 'User-agent' : getRandomUserAgent() }
    geturls = getURL()
    getquery = xquery
    for i in geturls:
        url = i.rstrip()
        try:
            for l in getquery:
                query = l.rstrip()
                r = requests.get(url+query,headers=my_headers,verify=False,timeout=60)
                soup = BeautifulSoup( r.text, 'lxml' )
                div = ['']
                check = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('|'.join("find text")))
                if check:
                    valid = (r.url+'variable ')
                    print(valid)
                    break
                if not check:
                    print(r.url+' Not Variable ')
                    pass
                pass
            else:
                print(r.url+' Not Variable ')
                pass
        except ConnectionError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            continue
        except TimeoutError:
            continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
            pass
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError) as e:
            continue
        except NewConnectionError:
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
        except:
            continue
def main():
    try:
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(8) as e:
            xquery = getQUERY()
            e.map(URLopen, xquery)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('GoodBye!')
        sys.exit()
    except:
        print('Usage Help ! : start.py list.txt timeout processe')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        os.system('clear')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. Can you restate it? Something to do with the `pass` statements, maybe? What do you expect that to do? `pass` is a no-op, so doing nothing is what I'd expect. If you're not asking about the `pass` statements, then I really have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: i mean if the if statement pass its sitiil go to nex query check the code dude

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Before jumping to any conclusions, please extract a [mcve], so you can inspect the behaviour in isolation. Many things resolve themselves doing so. That said,  as a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadPoolExecutor`'s`map` method will call `URLopen` for every element in `xquery`. In that case, `URLopen` input parameter should only be a single query. You function currently is processing a list of queries. try refactoring `URLopen` to process only one query and see if it works out.

You can try the following code snippet:

```
def URLopen(query):
    my_headers = {'User-agent': getRandomUserAgent()}
    geturls = getURL()
    for i in geturls:
        url = i.rstrip()
        try:
            query = query.rstrip()
            r = requests.get(url + query, headers=my_headers, verify=False, timeout=60)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            div = ['']
            check = soup.body.find_all(string=re.compile('|'.join("find text")))
            if check:
                valid = (r.url + 'variable ')
                print(valid)
                break
            else:
                print(r.url + ' Not Variable ')
        except ConnectionError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            continue
        except TimeoutError:
            continue
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            continue
        except requests.exceptions.SSLError:
            pass
        except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, ValueError) as e:
            continue
        except NewConnectionError:
            continue
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            sys.exit()
        except:
            continue
```